# Why is my unit test failing when all I'm trying to do is test the endpoint of the home view?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, phpunit

I'm on `Laravel Framework 5.6.38` - I'm doing a simple test where I'd like to just test the homepage, it should return a `200` but instead, it's returning the error below.  The home page is defined in the web.php file so no issues there.

I'm just not sure how to go about fixing this.

```
Time: 274 ms, Memory: 20.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\UserTest::testExample
Expected status code 200 but received 302.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:124
/home/vagrant/project/tests/Feature/UserTest.php:19
```

Here's `UserTest.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/home');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Here's `.env.testing` file:

```
APP_NAME="Project"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:somekey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://local.test
```

Here's `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="local"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: You are getting a 302, which is a redirect. Does it work in your browser?

Comment: @ChinLeung yeah it works on my browser

Comment: Do you need to be authenticated to visit the `/home` route?

Comment: @TimLewis oh yeah, I do *facepalm*.  I need to call something that's auth oriented in the method in order to make this work, right?

Comment: Yeah, that 302 redirect is kicking you back to login screen to authenticate  I don't really know the approach to doing that, haven't used this suite for Laravel testing (yet), but that's likely the core of your issue here.

Comment: @TimLewis gotcha, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

If you are redirected (302) because you are not logged in on your tests, you can try to mock a User and set the user as logged in before running the test.

Snippet of user being created and login in the 'api' driver:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$this->be($user, 'api');
```

You can also try to skip the middleware that checks the login:

```
$this->withoutMiddleware(AuthMiddlware::class);
```

If it works, I would create a Trait and add it to the test cases you need.